# How to Encrypt a password to check for a correct login

Tags: python, tkinter, encryption, cryptography

So today i decided to make a program that tests for correct login and password. When testing for the password i use `password_insert.get() == 'Encrypted password'`, i was able to encrypt my password and got a string that was along the lines of 'ujghtsihjsohjiohfjh', i then inserted that string into the 'encrypted password' but now the `password_insert.get()` needs to be encrypted using the same method to match it. i thought that using the original method which was using .encrypt would work, so it would look like this `password_insert.get.encrypt()` but of course that doesn't work, so how am i able to do this?
full code

```
from tkinter import *
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

root = Tk()

root.title("Login Tester")

def login1():
    if email_insert.get() == 'Test' and password_insert.get() == 'Encrypted password':
        print("Success")
        root.destroy()
    else:
        root.destroy()
        root2 = Tk()
        
        check_button = Label(root2, text="Fail", font=44).grid(row=0, column=0)
        spacer = Label(root2, text="               ").grid(row=1, column=0)
        root2.mainloop()

        
# Def labels
email_label = Label(root, text="Email", font=22)
password_label = Label(root, text="Password", font=22)

# grid labels
email_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=28, pady=10)
password_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

# def text boxes
email_insert = Entry(root, width=35, borderwidth=5)
password_insert = Entry(root, width=35, borderwidth=5, show="*")

# grid text boxes
email_insert.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2)
password_insert.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2)

#def button
login = Button(root, text="Login", command= login1)

login.grid(row=2, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://medium.com/satyam-kulkarni/a-simple-login-system-with-python-tkinter-73e4c90820d7

Comment: To deal with passwords start with some tutorial that explains "hash", "salt", and "rounds".

Comment: Not recommended to use multiple instances of `Tk()`, change `root2 = Tk()` to `root2 = Toplevel()` and `root2.mainloop()` is not necessary